# Call custom »destructor« only when vector containing object is deleted

Tags: c++, oop, stdvector

Adding a destructor to an object is a handy way of making sure that it cleans up whatever pointers it may have allocated, without depending on that the programmer remembers to do this.

However when using the dynamically sized vector, the vector sometimes spontaneously moves all objects to a new location, as soon as a new object is added to said vector (EDIT: if the size of the vector surpasses the allocated area of data, then the vector copies its content to a new location), resulting in the destructor of said object being called, just after all its data has been copied to a new location:

```
...
my_vector.push_back(my_object(...));//destructor of all my_objects before this newly added one may just have been called
...
```

This is mostly not a problem, since all the data is copied, but it could be problematic if the object in question, in its destructor, deletes an object or array pointed by a pointer, or in any other way un-assign some loaded data – for instance, deletes an openGL texture, buffer or shader:

```
...
    ~my_object()
    {
        delete[] myArray;
        delete myPointer;
        glDeleteTexture(myTexture);
        //the pointers and texture location may have been copied to the new location, but the data to which they point have been deleted
    }
...
my_vector.push_back(my_object(...));//destructor of all my_objects before this newly added one may just have been called - myPointer, myArray and myTexture now point to no data
...
```

Now the old objects still in the vector, which were copied to a new location, points to no data, which will be a problem.
This problem can, of course, be solved by adding a custom `unassign` function, which is manually called when the entire vector should be deleted:

```
...
    ~my_object()
    {
    }

    void unassign()
    {
        delete[] myArray;
        delete myPointer;
        glDeleteTexture(myTexture);
        //the pointers and texture location may have been copied to the new location, but the data to which they point have been deleted
    }
...
my_vector.push_back(my_object(...));//destructor of all my_objects before this newly added one may just have been called - nevermind
...
for (my_object& M: my_vector) M.unassign();//if this line is not forgotten everything is now unassigned
...
```

The problem is however that I when using this approach often forget to call this unassign function, leaving pointers to objects, pointers to arrays and OpenGL textures, buffers and programs not deleted.

Therefore my question is if it is possible to program the objects, such that they delete their pointers, textures or any similar data, when and only when the entire vector is deleted, but without requiring the programmer to remember to add a specific line

Comment: `the vector sometimes spontaneously moves all objects to a new location` Well that's alarming. What makes you think it's doing that?

Comment: Make sure you're following the "rule of 3" (or 5 or zero); what you're describing should be a non-issue if you have correct copy/move constructors.

Comment: You probably doesn't respect rule of 5/3/0 for `my_object`.

Comment: Is the [C++11 std::shared_ptr<>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/) an option? It could simplify copying and moving of objects which refer to subdata that should only be created once and then only reference in different instances of the classes when your class is copied.

Comment: @PaulR. shared_ptr would properly help when it comes to pointers, but the problem would still be there with library-specific data, such as OpenGL textures.

Comment: then create a base class containing a GLuint- or uintptr_t-handle with move-methods implemented and copy-methods deleted (simply copying the handle and set the original one to zero indicating an empty handle. Don't forget to declare the move-operator= as noexcept). A derived class may then create and free opengl-objects without worrying about moving/copying.

Comment: Listen to @Mat ... you don't need any new indirection through pointers (smart or not). Just proper copy (and possibly move) constructors (and assignment operators).

Comment: Wrapping  `GLTexture` and other 3rd library with smart pointer should help.

Comment: [I did it like that](https://github.com/GLDRorg/GLDR/blob/master/src/glid.hpp) a while ago. Served as a base for [other primitives](https://github.com/GLDRorg/GLDR/blob/bananu7/src/Texture.hpp#L17-L34)

Comment: This is where move constructors/assignment operators come into play.  If you have a class that it is not really copyable you move it and set the class you moved from in to a empty but deleteable state.

Answer (score 0):

"it is possible to program the objects, such that they delete their pointers, textures or any similar data  when and only when the entire vector is deleted".

No. Objects do not know they're in a vector, let alone what happens to that vector.

It's not relevant either. An object should destroy its members whenever the object itself is destroyed. This may sound wasteful, but thanks to move operations this can be quite cheap. `std::vector` will call your move constructor to create a new object, when vector knows it will destroy the old object afterwards. You take advantage of this by stealing the members of the old object, so when that is destroyed it finds itself without members.

Obviously this only works for members that you can steal. You'd just copy a plain `int`.